# Getting Keys and Values of a JSON Array in the specific order

Tags: arrays, json, loops

I'm very new to Java, I'm using it to teach my Lego NXT Robot some ways out of a labyrinth. The algorithm parameters shall be outsourced and loaded in the code, so thats why I use JSON.
MY JSON file is pretty simple (lefthand algorthm):

```
{"algorithm": 
    {
      "onGapLeft": "moveLeft",
      "onGapFront": "moveForward",
      "onGapRight": "moveRight",
      "default": "moveBackward"
    }
}
```

It's very important that this file is read in it's order. I.e. if you change Left and Right the algorithm would become a Right Hand Algorithm.
This is the Java Code so far, I hope you understand what I'm trying to do. BTW: I'm using [JSON.simple](https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/)!

```
private static void loadAlgorithm() throws InterruptedException {

        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();


            Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("lefthand.json"));             
            JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
            JSONArray algorithm = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("algorithm");
            int length = algorithm.size();

        for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            switch (algorithm[i].key)
            {
                 case "onGapLeft" :  leftPos = i; break;
                 case "onGapFront": frontPos = i; break;
                 case "onGapRight": rightPos = i; break;
                 default: break;
            }

            switch (algorithm[i].value)
            {
                 case "moveLeft"    : directionAlgorithm[i] = direction.Left;     break;
                 case "moveFront"   : directionAlgorithm[i] = direction.Forward;  break;
                 case "moveRight"   : directionAlgorithm[i] = direction.Right;    break;
                 case "moveBackward": directionAlgorithm[3] = direction.Backward; break;
                 default: break;
            }
        }           
    }
```

I'll need to know now wether it is possible to get the key string (where I used algorithm[i].key actually) and the same for the value string (algorithm[i].value).

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: I don't think it solves your problem completely, but you've misinterpreted "algorithm" as a JSONArray. It's actually a JSONObject, meaning just like how you got "algorithm" from the root object, you can get "onGapLeft"/"onGapFront" values from the algorithm object. Arrays have their values declared sequentially with [] brackets and commas, and do not have string labels (ex.: ["moveLeft", "moveRight"]

Comment: Yeah, there's no "array" in that JSON.  And the order of entries in an "object" (map/dictionary) are "not defined" -- even if they arrive in one order the code that parses the JSON can legitimately rearrange them.

Comment: (One wonders why you have key names for the individual values, if they will always be in a given order.  It would make more sense to just have an array of `[moveLeft, moveForward, moveRight, moveBackward]`, if that's what you want.  Or make the key names be "firstMove", "secondMove", "thirdMove", "fourthMove".)

Comment: (See json.org for the JSON spec.  It takes only 5-10 minutes to learn.)

Comment: Thanks everyone! So if I change the JSON like zigdawgydawg stated below, it'll be sorted then?
@HotLicks: This would be a solution, but we want to have it more custamizable, tehrefore we've added this two value solution! :)

Comment: If you change it as ziggy suggested you'll get an "object" whose "algorithm" element is an "array" containing 4 "objects", each with two elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably change your JSON so that it is ordered, something like this:

```
{"algorithm": 
    [
        { "key": "onGapLeft", "value" : "moveLeft" },
        { "key": "onGapFront", "value" : "moveForward" },
        { "key": "onGapRight", "value" : "moveRight" },
        { "key": "default", "value" : "moveBackward" }
    ]
}
```

And then modify your Java accordingly.

Comment: Thanks! Does this solve the problem Katana314 stated, that my JSON file is not an array at the moment? :)
And is it then possible to iterate thorugh this via "algorithm[i].key"? i.e. algorithm[0].key would be OnGapLeft? :)

Comment: Yes...it does solve the problem that @Katana314 mentioned.  The `[...]` in JSON is a proper (and ordered) array.  As you are iterating through the `algorithm` JSONArray, get the JSONObject at each index with `JSONObject obj2 = (JSONObject) algorithm.get(i);` and then to get that object's key `obj2.get("key");`.  I hope that helps.

Comment: Okay! Now I have just one problem with the initialising. The line:
`Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("lefthand.json"));`
has an error saying: "Unhandled exception type ParseException"

Any suggestions? (As I said: I'm completely new to Java and Eclipse and sometimes I don't get what it wants to tell me :)

Comment: You'll either need to wrap that line in a try/catch block or explicitly specify that the `loadAlgorithm` method `throws ParseException`.  Here is more information about the two options: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3241571/try-catch-versus-throws-exception)

Comment: Thank you very much! 
This helped, the program compiled, everythings fine.
Big problem now: That damn Lego Robot doesn't understand simpleJSON.
I now have to work myself through a non library but java file json lib.. I hope that's not too complicated.

I think I'm going to cry a little bit now. Thanks anyways ;)

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with JSON , but Since JSONObject is backed by a HashMap, you may be able to get the keys and values into a array in the same order like below,

```
Map<K, V> map = new HashMap<K, V>();
K[] keys = new K[map.size()];
V[] values = new V[map.size()];
int index = 0;
for (Map.Entry<K, V> mapEntry : map.entrySet()) {
    keys[index] = mapEntry.getKey();
    values[index] = mapEntry.getValue();
    index++;
}
```