# when to throw FileNotFoundException

Tags: java

I called a method named `readFile()` in the `main` method, `readFile()` throws FileNotFoundException but `main` doesn't, like the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    readFile();
}

public static void readFile() throws FileNotFoundException{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("file.txt"));
    ...
}
```

When I compiled the program, I got an error at `readFile()` in the `main` method. It seems that I need to throw an exception in the header of `main` as well. Why do I need to throw exception in both headers of `main` and `readFile()`?

Comment: You need to catch it, not throw it.

Comment: What do you want to achieve by propagating this exception?

Comment: Because main calls readFile, and if readFile throws a FileNotFound exception then main will propogate up the exception if it doesn't catch it. So you either need to catch the exception in main or declare that it can throw one, albeit indirectly.

Comment: I think you're confusing people with "Why do I need to throw exception": I think you mean "why do I need to declare that main can throw the exception"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your options for handling `Exceptions` are to catch them and deal with them immediately or to throw them in the function and propagate the exception up to the caller of the function.

For `main`, it makes sense to `catch` and handle the exception there.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
  try {
    readFile();
  } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // Do something with `e`
  }
}

public static void readFile() throws FileNotFoundException {
  Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("file.txt"));
  // ...
}
```

However, you could also do something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
  readFile();
}

public static void readFile() {
  try {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("file.txt"));
    // ...
  } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // Do something with `e` or handle it accordingly.
  }
}
```

I would advise against throwing exceptions in the `main`, but after that it's really a matter of whether you have a "back up" for if something fails. For more information, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3241571/try-catch-versus-throws-exception) has fantastic detail.

Answer (score 8):

Java has some controversy about its exceptions. It has two classes of exceptions. Checked and unchecked. Any exception extending from RuntimeException or Error is unchecked and does not need to be caught or explicitly declared as throwable in a method signature.

FileNotFound is however a checked exception and must either be caught or declared as throwable in the method signature.

The basic idea is that checked exceptions are ones that you may be able to recover from while unchecked exceptions are ones coming from a most likely unrecoverable error in programming.

You can read all about it here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/runtime.html

Answer (score 5):

Think of the `throws` keyword as a promise; You're saying you're not going to catch the exception now, but you're going to catch it at the calling statement.

The code you currently have in your `readFile` method seems perfectly valid, but you need to wrap the calling statement in a `try-catch` to appropriately handle the exception.

Answer (score 1):

there is no point to throw an exception in main method- this is the entry point to the program, which means no other method will catch this exception and handle it. you should catch and handle the exception here - either log the error, give a clear message to the user, read some other file, whatever, but throwing exception is wrong here.

Comment: What if some other Java class calls `main` instead?

Comment: @MadProgrammer - then this is bad programming and shouldn't be done (IMHO). main is an entry point, should not be called internally

Comment: None the less, it gets done, just because we think it's a bad doesn't stop it from happening, and in fact might be done by design. You can throw the exception from `main` and the JVM will handle it (just like to does uncaught exceptions), but that would require more details ;) - My personal preference is to deal with it in the `main` method, but, that's not always possible

Answer (score 1):

You need to catch the exception

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    readFile();
}

public static void readFile() {
   try {
      Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("file.txt"));
      ...
   } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
      // Error message
   } catch (Exception ex) {
      // Incase a different exception is caught
   }
}
```