# Set up Android iAP Purchases - error

Tags: java, android, multithreading, in-app-purchase

I am trying to set up iAP for a Premium membership. 
I've added my app and my signed apk to the developer console and then I started following this example: [Implementing In-app Billing](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html)

I've noticed a tricky part that says:

> **Warning:** Do not call the getSkuDetails method on the main thread. Calling this method triggers a network request which could block your main thread. Instead, create a separate thread and call the getSkuDetails method from inside that thread.

so this is the code I wrote:

```
public class class...
Bundle querySkus = new Bundle();


/** gestisce gli acquisti in app */
IInAppBillingService mService;

ServiceConnection mServiceConn = new ServiceConnection() {
    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
        mService = IInAppBillingService.Stub.asInterface(service);
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
        mService = null;
    }
    };
```

and in my `onCreate()` method:

```
Intent serviceIntent = new Intent("com.android.vending.billing.InAppBillingService.BIND");
    serviceIntent.setPackage("com.android.vending");
    bindService(serviceIntent, mServiceConn, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

    ArrayList<String> skuList = new ArrayList<String>();
    skuList.add("premiumUpgrade");


    querySkus.putStringArrayList("chords_premium", skuList);

    AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Bundle skuDetails = mService.getSkuDetails(3, getPackageName(), "inapp", querySkus);
        }
    });
```

now on `Bundle skuDetails = mService.getSkuDetails(3, getPackageName(), "inapp", querySkus);` I'm getting:

> Unhandled Exception: android.os.RemoteException

First of all, **how do I fix it?**

I'm implementing this code in my main activity even though the button the should redirect to the buying dialog is in another activity. **Am I doing it right? Do I need to pass it to the other Activity? if so, how? Is it better that I put the whole code that handles iAP inside the specific activity?**

**EDIT: **
I've tried to catch the exception like this:

```
AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {Bundle skuDetails = mService.getSkuDetails(3, getPackageName(), "inapp", querySkus); }
            catch (RemoteException e) {e.printStackTrace();};
        }
    });
```

It won't work becuase I cannot set `int response = skuDetails...` (in the doc linked above)

Comment: Is it compilation error or runtime error?

Comment: compilation error

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested your code.. but I think you can try this:

```
    AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Bundle skuDetails = null;
                    try {
                        skuDetails = mService.getSkuDetails(3,
                           getPackageName(), "inapp", querySkus); 
                    } catch (RemoteException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    int response = skuDetails.whateverYouWantToDoWithThis();
                }
     });
```

OR

```
AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() throws RemoteException {
                    Bundle skuDetails = mService.getSkuDetails(3,
                           getPackageName(), "inapp", querySkus); 
                    int response = skuDetails.whateverYouWantToDoWithThis();
                }
     });
```

Read more about throws vs try-catch here: [try/catch versus throws Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3241571/try-catch-versus-throws-exception)