# NullPointerException in JUnit

Tags: exception, nullpointerexception

I am running this JUint test method, and while running getting an exception `NullPointerException`. How to handle this exception over here?

```
@Test
public void testDivision1() {
    System.out.println("testDivision");`
    Operation instance = new Operation(100, 2, null);
    int res = instance.calculate();
    assertEquals(50, res);

}
```

Comment: What does `Operation` look like?

Comment: public class Operation {
 private final int firstOperand;
 private final int secondOperand;
 private final EnumOp operator;

 public Operation(int firstOperand, int secondOperand, EnumOp operator) {

  this.firstOperand = firstOperand;
  this.secondOperand = secondOperand;
  this.operator = operator;
 }

 public int calculate() {
  return operator.calculate(firstOperand, secondOperand);
 }
}

Comment: Please update your question with that code.

Answer (score 0):

As you pass `null` for `EnumOp operator` here

```
Operation instance = new Operation(100, 2, null);
```

I assume this operation fails

```
return operator.calculate(firstOperand, secondOperand);
```

You should set a valid `EnumOp` for the test.

Comment: @Test
 public void testDivision1() throws NullPointerException {
  try {
   System.out.println("testDivision");
   Operation instance = new Operation(100, 2, null);
   int res = instance.calculate();
   assertEquals(50, res);
  } catch (NullPointerException e) {
   System.out.println("error");
  }

 }

Comment: It is possible to add throws and try,catch at same time?

Comment: It is possible, but it makes no sense here. You say 'this method throws NPE, but I'll catch it anyhow'. Think about, what you want to test? Test if the division works right? Or if an exception is thrown?

Comment: yes, if I will not use throws also,no problem . Actually, I am not getting wen to add throws and when to add try,catch.

Comment: Have look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3241571/try-catch-versus-throws-exception Was my answer useful? Then accept it and close the issue for now.

Comment: Then please accept it and show other users, your question is solved: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work