# Assigning throws clause in method

Tags: java, exception, program-entry-point

How can I use the `throws` clause in the  main method signature to handle an exception, as shown in the following example?

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Exception {

    public static void main(String ... args) throws IOException {
        ioExceptionTest();
    }

    public static void ioExceptionTest() throws IOException {
        File file = new File("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\Test.txt");

        try {
            file.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw e;
        }
    }
}
```

For me it doesn't make sense.

Comment: Please put code itself in the question, not images. [Edit] your post according

Comment: Your answer might be given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3241571/try-catch-versus-throws-exception). Take a look.

Answer (score 2):

If a method uses a `throws` clause it the method signature, then any exceptions raised in that method will be raised to the caller where the method was called. The caller can either choose to handle the exception with a try catch block, or use a throws clause to raise the exception to whoever called it.

A throws clause on the main method means the exception will be raised to the [Java Virtual Machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine), which will handle the exception, and print the stack trace.

```
class Example {
    // handle exception with a try catch block
    public static void main(String ... args) {
        try {
            myMethod();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // handle the exception
        }
    }

    // raise exception to the Java Virtual Machine
    public static void main(String ... args) throws Exception {
            myMethod();
    }

    static void myMethod() throws Exception {
        // do something which may throw an Exception, such as
        throw new Exception("Meaningful description");
    }
}
```