# How to leave the error catching to the subclass?

Tags: java, java-ee-8

```
public class First {
protected void method1() throws CustomException {
    int number=10/0;
    System.out.println("method 1" + number);
    throw new CustomException("Divided by zero");
}
public class Second extends First {
protected void method2() {
        method1();
    
}
public class Third extends Second {
protected void method3(){
    try {
        method2();
        }
        catch (CustomException ex)
        {
            System.out.println("Caught the exception");
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        } 
}
```

In this code first throws an exception and I want to catch it from third (second will not handle error). But second's method call won't let me pass. How can I fix this?

Comment: by not calling the method from the second class. Make that class abstract, and force the user to use the child class

Comment: Maybe explain more why that's the use case/implementation. There are multiple solutions for this answer, such cutting the middle man, not declaring the `CustomException` in `method1`, etc.

Comment: I have to catch in third and log its' details in a file. But I can't delete the second. Because it's kinda homework.

Comment: @Stultuske Sorry but I don't understand what do you mean

Comment: if the user is allowed to directly call the method in the parent class, it is not possible to say that the child class must handle the exception. so, make sure only the child classes methods are publicly visible

Comment: Possible duplicate of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46881785/12695027), that explains it better than I did. I got the impression that is wasn't really the subclassing that posed the problem :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For checked exceptions (*not* any `RuntimeException`), they must be either handled or thrown by the method that calls another method that throws the exception. This is also explained in more depth in the tutorial by Oracle on [Exceptions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/index.html).

This example is based on your code:

```java
class Testing{
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Third t = new Third();
    t.method3();
  }
}
```

and it will print:

```
Caught the exception
Divided by zero
```

Added the missing implementation of `CustomException`:

```java
class CustomException extends Exception{
  CustomException(){
    super();
  }
  CustomException(String message){
    super(message);
  }
}
```

Note that your code would never get to actually throwing your exception, as division by zero would be thrown first. `ArithmeticException` is a `RuntimeException` and therefore not a checked exception, and it doesn't need or warrant any declaration. I've removed it so your exception is thrown:

```java
class First {
  protected void method1() throws CustomException {
  // will cause "java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero" not CustomException
  //  int number=10/0;
  //  System.out.println("method 1" + number);
    throw new CustomException("Divided by zero");
  }
} // missing end brace
```

The reason why your `Second`'s method call "won't let me pass" is because you're throwing an `Exception` in `method1` which you are calling in your `Second`'s method call. So you need to either wrap your call to `method1()` in a try-catch block, or `throws` it. Since you "want to catch it from third", you need to `throws` it in the declaration of the method:

```java
class Second extends First {
  // error: unreported exception CustomException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
  // protected void method2() {  // your version

  protected void method2() throws CustomException {
    method1();
  }
} // missing end brace
```

This is unchanged, except for the added brace:

```java
class Third extends Second {
  protected void method3(){
    try {
      method2();
    } catch (CustomException ex) {
      System.out.println("Caught the exception");
      System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    } 
  } 
} // missing end brace
```