# How do I add a sleep to my Retry TestNG method?

Tags: java, selenium, exception, testng, thread-sleep

I'm currently implementing a method of IRetryAnalyzer in combination with IAnnotationTransformer to perform a retry when my tests fail. I want to add a Thread.sleep() when the Retry occurs. Here's what I currently have:

```
public boolean retry(ITestResult result){
    if (retryCount < maxRetryCount) {
        retryCount++;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

When I add Thread.sleep() it requires that I add an thrown Exception for the Retry method:

```
public boolean retry(ITestResult result) throws Exception{
    if (retryCount < maxRetryCount) {
        retryCount++;
        Thread.sleep(5);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

However, the "Exception" gives me an error: "Overriden method does not throw java.lang.Exception". It seems like I can't actually add a Sleep to this retry despite how much I've tried. Does anyone know a work around?

Comment: Why do you want a sleep there? Why would you want a 5s sleep anywhere on a rerun? If you really need one, you could put it somewhere else.

Comment: @JeffC I'm trying to address an issue in my test suite around inconsistent api and page load times. I understand I could create a method that waits for elements to appear and then continues but the suite I'm coming into is so large that it would take a while to implement a method like this in all my 1000+ tests.

Comment: Adding a 5s sleep when a test fails is not the way to address page load times, etc. I'm not even sure how this would even help.

Comment: @JeffC If you have another way to improve test suite stability I'd love to hear it.

Comment: You address the actual problem. If page load times are inconsistent, you deal with that directly. You add waits that allow the page time to load, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a difference between 'throws' declaration and the 'try-catch' block. The difference is, 'try-catch' swallows the exception and 'throws' will let it propagate. Refer the below link:

[try/catch versus throws Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3241571/try-catch-versus-throws-exception)

As retry is an overridden method, there are some rules about method overriding with exception handling.

The rules are:

1. If the superclass method does not declare an exception, subclass overridden method cannot declare the checked exception but it can declare unchecked exception.

2. If the superclass method declares an exception, subclass overridden method can declare same, subclass exception or no exception but cannot declare parent exception.

So, declare an exception according to the above rules or surround the 'Thread.sleep(5000)' with try-catch block like below.

```
try {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //do nothing
    }
```

Note:

The Thread.sleep() will actually consider value as milliseconds, so use 5000 instead of 5.

Answer (score 1):

Catch and suppress the `InterruptedException` that would be thrown.

```
try {
    Thread.sleep(5);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    //do nothing
}
```

This will prevent you from needing to add the `throws` clause to the method definition.

Comment: Thank you! This worked great. I chose another answer as the accepted answer as it gives some more links too but this is the same solution.

Comment: As @J.Jeffreys mentions _...this is the same solution..._ I liked the precision with `InterruptedException`. I will avoid catching the _Base Exception_.

Answer (score 0):

`Thread.sleep(long)` could throw `InterrupedException`.
You can include it into a `try catch` block and also remove `throws Exception` from method.

```
public boolean retry(ITestResult result){

    if (retryCount < maxRetryCount) {

        retryCount++;

        try{

            Thread.sleep(5);

        }catch(Exception e){}

        return true;

    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked great. I chose another answer as the accepted answer as it gives some more links too but this is the same solution.